# Doctrine Connection Refused from Symfony Docker Container to MariaDB Container

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, mariadb

Banging my head at 2:30 a.m.

I have three Docker containers **MariaDB**, **Nginx** and **PhpFpm**.

MariaDB opens up 3306/tcp - no exposed port because all container share the same Docker Network.

Symfony starts up in PhpFpm and is exposed via Nginx on port 8081.

So *myhost.com:8081* shows my Symfony application.

1. When I `docker exec bash` into my PhpFpm container and execute `bin/console doctrine:schema:create` schema is created, MariaDB has a new table.
2. Of course I clear the cache and warm it up for APP_ENV=prod
3. var/log and var/cache have set correct permissions.

No matter what I do, when using the PDO connection within my Symfony application's controller I get an

> Connection refused error

visible in my *prod.log* within the container.

I tried *.env* with several options, most prominent are:

1. DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:pass@hostname:8084/db" (here I set -p 8084:3306 for MariaDB Container)

and

2. DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:pass@mariadbcontainername:3306/db" (here I did not expose any DB port as mentioned above)

Does anyone have an idea where to look and what to test?

I can even verify that my `bin/console doctrine...` commands are already getting a Connection Refused error when I change the DATABASE_URL to a nonsense value.

P.S.: Due to server restrictions I don't use docker-compose but simply docker run.

Comment: nginx sets env vars when forwarding stuff to php-fpm, those are potentially overriding any local stuff set. otherwise: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production you could add a file into public that just outputs the initialized env vars.

Comment: thank you, that was indeed the issue. found some fastcgi_params in my nginx conf which have been incorrect. oh my... this took me many hours. thanks a lot.